# Python List return third value associated with first two values

Tags: python, list, function

I'm writing a program for a recommender system using Python. I'm trying to implement a function that takes the first two elements of a list, and returns the third one associated with those first two. Let me elaborate.

The data that I have as as such:

```python
train_data = [ [0, 0, 5],
               [0, 1, 4],
               [0, 2, 2],
             ...
               [900, 900, 2] ]
```

Basically it's a list of lists, and each individual element is comprised of `[user_id, item_id, rating]`.

Is there any way that I provide the first two elements and return the rating value?

For example: `return_third(0, 0) = 5`.

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to do specifically is create a function that calculates the loss between our prediction for user `i` and item `j`.

The total number of users is 900, and the total number of items is 1000, so the data matrix that I've created is `900 x 1000` for each user and their corresponding ratings.

I want to calculate the loss from the predictions and the actual ratings in `train_data`.

There is only going to be one rating for each `user_id` and `item_id` pair. Some values are missing, but that is for a separate question I feel.

Comment: Is there only ever going to be one rating for one user_id and item_id pair?

Comment: Yes, thanks for bringing it up. Let me edit in the details for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you can just make a dictionary where the keys are a tuple of the first two elements of the sublists, and the values are the third element:

```
d = {(user_id, item_id): rating for user_id, item_id, rating in train_data}

print(d[0, 0])  # 5
```

This will only return values that you have defined in your list.

Comment: just wondered why both print(d[0,0]) and print(d[(0,0)]) worked in this case. Initially, I thought only print(d[(0,0)]) worked since the key was a tuple. Thanks!

Comment: A tuple is a comma-separated sequence of items. The parentheses around them is just to make what is in the tuple unambiguous. `0, 0` is equivalent to `(0, 0)` in the same way that `1+1` is equivalent to `(1+1)`